# Coldfuson CFScript "setSQL" method was not found

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, components

I've got a Coldfusion component, with a method in it called **getColumnNames**

This just queries a MySQL table, and returns the columnlist:

```
remote string function getColumnNames() {
    qProcessCars = new Query();
    qProcessCars.setDataSource('#APPLICATION.dsn#');
    qProcessCars.setSQL('SELECT * FROM sand_cars WHERE 1 LIMIT 1');
    qProcessCars = qProcessCars.Execute().getResult();

    return qProcessCars.columnlist;
}
```

If I access this remotely in the browser, with **page.cfc?method=getColumnNames**, then I get the expected list of columns back.

However, if I try to access this from inside another method within the component, I get an error

```
remote string function otherFunction() {
   ...
   sColumns = getColumnNames();
   ...
}
```

The error dump for the above code returns the message "The setSQL method was not found".

So can anyone help me find out why it works as a remote call, but not when called from another method inside the same component.

Comment: Ah I've answered my own question again. Sorry.

I've used the same name *qProcessCars* else where in the component, I hadn't put **var** in front of them. 

I don't know WHY that was causing the problem, but it was. Maybe **setSQL** can only be called once per *query* object?

I can't actually answer this yet as I've only just listed it

Comment: Oops, looks like you've answered it before I've completed my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem may be caused some kind of race conditions. If you make few calls which interfere, at some point qProcessCars may already be query result, so invoking method is not possible.

I would try to make the `qProcessCars` variable local scoped (`var qProcessCars = new Query();`
) and/or try to use another variable name for query results.

Next possible step is to enclose the query building/executing code into named lock.

Answer (score 0):

Ah I've answered my own question again. Sorry.

I've used the same name *qProcessCars* else where in the component, I hadn't put **var** in front of them.

I don't know WHY that was causing the problem, but it was. Maybe **setSQL** can only be called once per *query* object?